How to set/pass environment variables via terraform to a aws glue script?
I am setting up an glue job in aws via terraform and a python file which does the ETL on data  (see example below ) . how do i pass environment variables from my terraform code to my script , such that i can inject some environment variables to my script, essentially read it via => os.getenv('some_key'..
myscript.py
import sys
import os
frm awsglue.transforms import *
...

os.getenv(some_key, default = None)   


terraform
resource "aws_glue_job" "example" {
  name     = "example job"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  number_of_workers=4

  command {
    name            = "gluestreaming"
    script_location = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.test.data}/my_script.py"
  }
  # ... other configuration ...

  default_arguments = {
    # ... potentially other arguments ...
    "--continuous-log-logGroup"          = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example.name
    "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log" = "true"
    "--enable-continuous-log-filter"     = "true"
    "--enable-metrics"                   = ""
  }
}


Can you try using the job parameters --curstomer-driver-env-vars and/or --customer-executor-env-vars?
Based on this docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html), the following example usage is given:
"—customer-driver-env-vars", "CUSTOMER_KEY1=VAL1,CUSTOMER_KEY2=\"val2,val2 val2\"",
"—customer-executor-env-vars", "CUSTOMER_KEY3=VAL3,KEY4=VAL4"

See the enforced syntax section, where you need to start with the CUSTOMER_ prefix.
Do let me know if this works for you.

You can directly add any custom environment variables in the default_arguments block. AWS Glue will then pass these variables to your script as command-line arguments.
Your Terraform will look like this:
default_arguments = {
    "--continuous-log-logGroup"          = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example.name
    "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log" = "true"
    "--enable-continuous-log-filter"     = "true"
    "--enable-metrics"                   = ""
    
    # Add your custom environment variable here
    "--your_desired_environment_variable" = "your_value"
  }
}

Then you can easily retrieve this in your job script:
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

    
# Retrieve the environment variable
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME", "your_desired_environment_variable"])
your_desired_variable = args["your_desired_environment_variable"]

